# Angular HTTP GET Automatically Changing Dates?

Tags: angularjs, json

Does angular automatically parse dates returned in JSON from an `$http` request? I'm struggling to understand why my GET request in the browser results in a certain JSON and the JSON `console.log()` from my `$http` request results in a different JSON. The only difference is the dates same to be turned into UNIX timestamps even though in the database (and in the browser GET request) they are stored as `MMMM Do YYYY`.

In the browser GET request my JSON excerpt looks like:

```
"date":"July 18th 2016"
```

In the `$http` console log from this code:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/admin/getOrders'
      }).then(function successCallback(html) {
        console.log(html.data);
        //results in same excerpt as date:"1468814400000"
```

Edit: It's not even a corresponding timestamp so I wonder what is going on in the `$http` request... but it is the corresponding object.

Comment: Well when I remove my subsequent code it results as expected, I don't understand though why it would `console.log()` at that line as something that it isn't at that line, because whatever modifications happened to the date happened after that line...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Angular date filter in your template then yes, Angular will format the timestamp string as a date.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Without seeing your HTML I can only assume this is what is happening, the timestamp you have given "1468814400000" *is* July 18th 2016.

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.timestamp = '1468814400000';
  });
```

Template:

```
Date: {{ timestamp | date }}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZGjKLs9wXA0xqc3Rqd6?p=preview